# Настройка apache 2.4

Tags: apache, httpd

Как настроить "apache 2.4", чтобы отправляя файлы в папку "C:\www\site1" или "C:\www\site2", заходя на http://site1 или http://site12, мы попадали на соответствующий.
Знаю, как для каждого индивидуально настроить в файле httpd.conf:

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@may_domain.ru
    DocumentRoot c:/www/site1
    ServerName site1
    ErrorLog logs/mysite-error.log
    CustomLog logs/mysite-access.log common 
</VirtualHost>
```

Но тут для каждого нужно создавать такую запись, и в "hosts" нужно добавить:

```
127.0.0.1   site1
```

А как сделать проще? Создать один раз, для всех?
Сделать что-то на подобии работы "денвера"?

Comment: Посмотрите, пожалуйста, вот [этот][1] вопрос.


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/354139/

Comment: Спасибо. Но не совсем получилось. Удалил все и добавил вот этот код:

DocumentRoot c:/www
VirtualDocumentRoot c:/www/%2/

Сайты (site1) которые были прописаны в host - отобразились. А сайты которые не были в host нет.
В чем может быть дело?